# Try catch ignored?

Tags: jdbc, clojure

The following code creates a new table in the db. I would like it to catch any sql errors and continue running should the table already exists. However, when I execute the code, if the table already exists, I get an exception as expected but the code exits during compilation. Is the try catch being ignored?

Code:

```
 (ns app.storage
  (:import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource
           (clojure.lang ExceptionInfo))
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :refer :all]))

(def db {
         :classname   "org.sqlite.JDBC"
         :subprotocol "sqlite"
         :subname     "src/storage/journal.db"
         })

(defn create-db []
  (try
    (db-do-commands db
                    (create-table-ddl :entry
                                      [:id :primary :key]
                                      [:account "varchar(255)"]
                                      [:timestamp "timestamp"]
                                      [:debt "double(9,2)"]
                                      [:credit "double(9,2)"]))

    (catch ExceptionInfo e
      (println e))))

(create-db)
```

Exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.sql.BatchUpdateException: batch entry 0: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table entry already exists), compiling:(app/storage.clj:29:21)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7142)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:628)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5618)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at app.entry$eval2001$loading__4958__auto____2002.invoke(entry.clj:1)
    at app.entry$eval2001.invoke(entry.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:628)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5618)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at app.handler$eval1687$loading__4958__auto____1688.invoke(handler.clj:1)
    at app.handler$eval1687.invoke(handler.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init1139882819344867506.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: batch entry 0: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table entry already exists)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeBatch(Stmt.java:226)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$execute_batch.invoke(jdbc.clj:400)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$db_do_commands$fn__2331.invoke(jdbc.clj:671)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$db_transaction_STAR_.doInvoke(jdbc.clj:580)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$db_do_commands.doInvoke(jdbc.clj:670)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:628)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$db_do_commands.doInvoke(jdbc.clj:677)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630)
    at clojure.java.jdbc$db_do_commands.doInvoke(jdbc.clj:664)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at app.storage$create_db.invoke(storage.clj:21)
    at app.storage$eval2445.invoke(storage.clj:33)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    ... 76 more
Subprocess failed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `catch` is trying to catch exceptions of type `ExceptionInfo`. Try changing that to just `Exception` or `Throwable` and see if it catches the exception.

```
(catch Exception e
```

Notice in your stack trace the type of the exception being thrown is `java.sql.BatchUpdateException`, which doesn't inherit from `clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo`.
`ExceptionInfo` exceptions are typically created by calling `ex-info`, [docs here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ex-info). Your `catch` will only catch exceptions of the specified type (or sub-types of it).